# how to get values from html to javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Made a list in html and gave every option a value of numbers (0,1,2,...) and gave all the options the same class 'op' and then I want to save this values in an array in javascript but my code doesn't seem to work.

output should be [0,1,2,3,...] instead nothing happens

```
    let valuesfromhtml = document.getElementsByClassName('op').value;
        function test(value){ for (i=0 ; i < valuesfromhtml ; i++){
              let valuesofnames = [];
              valuesofnames.push(valuesfromhtml);
    console.log(valuesofnames)}
    }
```

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('op') is a collection of DOM elements ;  it would be easier if you provide a mini example code to illustrate your question please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ^ The important part of what Jojo just said, is that a collection of DOM elements does not have a `.value`.  You would have to loop over them to get each value

Comment: I used the for loop and it didn't work

Comment: what is dom elements please